# Cocoapods with github forked projects

Tags: ios, git, github, cocoapods, git-fork

I forked a project in github first time. I made some changes on project and commit to github.

I also create a new release on my fork for cocoapods see new version. I tried some ways but nothing work for using my fork on my another project.

my forked project url:
https://github.com/eflatunyazilim/Cluster

and I try these ways:

1:

```
 pod 'Cluster', :git => 'https://github.com/eflatunyazilim/Cluster.git', :commit => 'c20fe29a9fdf4139951f51aa7e45423a4e86a799'
```

2:

```
pod 'Cluster', :git => 'https://github.com/eflatunyazilim/Cluster'
```

3:

```
pod 'Cluster', :git => 'https://github.com/eflatunyazilim/Cluster.git'
```

When I run `pod install` and `pod update` on terminal, library project still use previous version of project.

> Using Cluster (1.0.9)

or

> Installing Cluster 1.0.9 (was 1.0.9)

Comment: Have you tried to change version number in Cluster.podspec?

Comment: Thanks, It worked :) Please add as answer your comment, I will aprove it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to change version number in your `podspec` file to

```
s.version = '1.1'
```